# How to update cache using subscriptons in apollo-client?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

In my react app, I have a component PageList (query) using subscribeToMore to update in real-time...
When I change to another route in my app, that subscription is closed (the list component is unmounted)...
But if another client add something to that list when I'm not in the route that have the PageList component loaded and then load the list again (and apollo cached the query in the PageList) the list doesn't contain the new item.

How should I use subscription in cases like that?